# Compare Last Modified Text File Date if its more then 12 hours- Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have written following `Classic ASP` code that display Last Modified date of `readme.txt` file as `11/26/2013 2:00:45 AM`.

What i am trying to do is to Compare Last Modified Text File Date if its more then 12 hours display **"Text file is old please update"** and if its not ELSE **"Text file is Latest"**

```
Dim objFSO, objFile, fname, fullname, my_array
fname= "readme.txt" 


Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Server.MapPath(fname))
Response.Write "Last Modified date of file "& objFile.Name & " = " & objFile.DateLastModified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the DateDiff function

```
DateDiff(interval, date1, date2 [,firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]])
```

example:

```
DateDiff( "h", now, objFile.DateLastModified)
```

have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp)

Comment: +1. But I'd suggest compare hours by using `minutes` or `seconds` instead `hours`. VBScript's date functions are strictly date-part aware when calculating the differences. `e.g.` Let's suppose that a file modified at 10:59, and the current time is 11 o'clock. The file modified just a minute ago but `DateDiff("h", #10:59:00#, #11:00:00#)` returns `1` as hour difference. Of course it's true but not in the real world. Just wanted to point out if the OP wants more accurate compare.